# Get last used Row and Column in an Excel Sheet without opening it

Tags: excel

Can I get the last used row number and column number for a Worksheet without opening it or using Interop (which is very slow)?

Thanks

Comment: Via VBA, C# Winforms, or some other platform?

Answer (score 0):

Without opening the sheet or the workbook in it's entirety? As Mike asked, what platform are you trying to do this in?

If you are trying to do it within the workbook you could create a module (open VBA with ALT+11), Insert, Module.

```
Sub lastusedcell()

Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

lastcol = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column

lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

MsgBox "Last used cell is (colnumber:rownumber) " & lastcol & ":" & lastrow


End Sub
```

Change "Sheet2" to the appropriate sheet name.
If you want to check for cells with formulas too, replace

```
LookIn:=xlValues with LookIn:=xlFormulas
```

Answer source [Source website with a few modifications for answer](http://www.listendata.com/2014/05/excel-vba-codes-to-find-last-used-row.html)

Then run the macro manually of create a button to do it or call the function if you need the values in VBA.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it earlier. I am using VB.NET. The only option I am aware so far is that using Excel.Interop, open the workbook and follow the code you mentioned.

Comment: I was wondering if this can be done without opening the workbook at all.

Comment: I'm not sure it can, define opening workbook, if we open it using code is that ok? Basically it won't physically (visually) open but programmatically open? Or not open whatsoever?

Comment: Preferably not open at all (like when we read data from excel file using oledb command, the file is not opened...I am not sure if you consider oledb command as programmatically opening the file). Every time I use Workbook.open command it opens in the background and is slow.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have found to this in the smartsheet documentation are the following keyboard shortcuts.  It appears that [Ctrl] + [Up Arrow} and [Ctrl] + [Left Arrow} are equivalent to [Ctrl] + [Home], and [Ctrl] + [Down Arrow} and [Ctrl] + [Right Arrow} are equivalent as [Ctrl] + [End].  I have not figured out an equivalent for the row navigation [Home] and [End] keyboard shortcuts.

- [Home]: Takes you to the first cell of the row you are currently on.
- [End]: Takes you to the last cell of the row are are currently on.
- [Ctrl] + [Home]: Takes you to the top left cell of your sheet.
- [Ctrl] + [End]: Takes you to the bottom right cell of your sheet.